# Does TInterfacedObject automatic memory management also work with C++Builder?

Tags: delphi, memory-management, c++builder, portability

The blog article "[Application Development with C++Builder and Delphi](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10103)" says that

> Almost anything you write in Delphi can easily be used in C++Builder
>   (...) You can write an object once for a Delphi project, and then
>   reuse it, unchanged, in a C++ project.

What about TInterfacedObject and its ref-count based automatic memory management, is this supposed to work with C++Builder too, without creating memory leaks? Or is the C++ based memory management incompatible with this ref-counted interface based technique?

The Delphi / C++ [documentation for TInterfacedObject](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.TInterfacedObject) says (highlighting by me):

> TInterfacedObject provides basic reference-counting functionality that
>   makes its descendent classes **useful in both Delphi and C++ code**.

Please note: this question is about direct compiling of Delphi / Object Pascal source code within a C++Builder project (afaik after doing a C++Builder precompiler run), not via dynamic linking (DLLs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ compiler does not directly implement reference counting on `__interface`s the way Delphi does. However, **there is a handy template in `System` that is used to wrap interfaces and provide reference counting, [`System::DelphiInterface`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.DelphiInterface)**, and this is [the standard C++ Builder way](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Implementing_Interfaces:_Delphi_and_C%2B%2B#Comparing_Delphi_and_C.2B.2B_Implementation_of_Interfaces) to write code similar in behaviour to Delphi.

Types using this are auto-generated in the .hpp file when compiling a .pas file using interfaces, and can also be easily created in your C++ code.  In fact you have probably seen them before - the autogenerated type names using this template all begin with `_di_`, eg the conversion of Delphi interface `IMyInterface` is `_di_IMyInterface`.

Copying straight from the help file link is this example:

```
// Interface that exposes an Add(..) method
 __interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{D0C74612-9E4D-459A-9304-FACE27E3577D}") IAdder  : public    System::IInterface 
 {
    virtual int __fastcall Add(int I, int J) = 0 ;
 };
 typedef System::DelphiInterface<IAdder> _di_IAdder;
```

Use `_di_Adder` everywhere in your C++ code instead of `IAdder`, and you will find your references reference counted.

Useful reading is the [entire section on DAX](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/C%2B%2BBuilder_Uses_DAX_for_ActiveX_and_COM), the new (as of XE) standard COM system in C++ Builder, which replaced ATL. It was possible to use it in earlier versions of CB (I did in 2010, for example) but it was unsupported. I like to think I encouraged it becoming officially supported through some conversations I had back then with some internal Embarcadero staff. (I have no idea if I really had any influence - I just like to think so :)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that to use reference counting, the original Delphi code stays unchanged - only the C++Builder side needs to apply the template and use the _di_ types? Did you encounter noteworthy cases (Delphi constructs) where C++Builder still leaked memory with this solution?

Comment: @mjn, that's correct. When you use a Delphi interface in C++ Builder, wrap it in the `DelphiInterface` template and always (and only) refer to it via the wrapped `_di_` type. If you follow that rules, reference counting will work. I have not encountered any memory leaks using that template.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ compiler won't emit code to call `AddRef` and `Release`. There is no special `interface` type in C++. Instead you'll need to ensure that the necessary calls to `AddRef` and `Release` are made. This is normally achieved by wrapping the raw interface in a smart pointer. In C++-Builder you might opt to use [`DelphiInterface<T>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DelphiInterface) or `TComInterface<T>`.

Serg touches on this topic in this article: [Consuming Delphi interfaces in Dephi and C++](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/consuming-delphi-interfaces-in-dephi-and-c/). The summary of that article is worth repeating:

> Some details worth being mentioned:
>
> - Delphi interfaces are always derived from IUnknown; a corresponding pure abstract C++ class should also define IUnknown methods;
> - Delphi interface type is kind of a pointer to the corresponding C++ abstract class, so sometimes we need one more level of indirection in
>     C++ code;
> - Delphi interface variables are always initialized to nil by the compiler; in C++ we need default constructor to implement the
>     nil-initialization;
> - Delphi interfaces are automatically released (i.e. call IUnknown._Release method) when an interface variable goes out of
>     scope; In C++ we implement the same functionality in destructor;
> - Interface assignment in Delphi implicitly calls _Addref and _Release methods of IUnknown; in C++ we overload the assignment operator to implement the interface assignment correctly;

Comment: This article is specific to calling Delphi DLLs from C++. My question is about direct compiling of Delphi / Object Pascal code within a C++Builder project (which afaik requires some preprocessor run but does not involve dynamic linking)

Comment: Irrespective of whether the Delphi code is in a DLL, or linked in, the C++ compiler isn't going to emit reference counting. An interface wrapper (like a smart pointer) is the usual way to get the calls to `AddRef` and `Release` generated.